# Can't @use a scss module in styles.scss with dependency in webpack config

Tags: webpack, sass

I have an angular application with a custom-webpack.config.js. I'm sharing my global scss variables across an Angular app. This is done via a custom webpack config. But I have a `@use sizes.scss` in my styles.scss that is depending on my global variables.scss.

custom-webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
              additionalData: `
                @use "src/assets/styles/_variables.scss" as *;
              `,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

_variables.scss

```
$sm: 375px;
$md: 1280px;
$lg: 1920px;

$breakpoints: (
    'sm': $sm,
    'md': $md,
    'lg': $lg,
);
```

sizes.scss

```
@each $key, $val in $breakpoints {
    @media screen and (max-width: #{$val - 1}) {
        .min-#{$key} {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: #{$val}) {
        .max-#{$key} {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

styles.scss

```
 @use 'assets/styles/sizes' as *;
```

I'm receiving this error message as `$breakpoints` is undefined:

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
╷
20 │     @each $key, $val in $breakpoints {

src\assets\styles_sizes.scss 20:22  @use
src\styles.scss 3:17                 root stylesheet

angular.json:

```
     ....
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
     ....
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    ....
```

It's like the styles.scss is being read before the additionalData in webpack config. Because when I'm moving `@use 'assets/styles/sizes' as *;` into additionalData in the wp config, the error will disappear. Reason for not doing so is that my sizes.scss shouldn't be global. Is there another way to solve this error?

"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.1",
"sass": "^1.55.0",
"sass-loader": "13.0.2",